# "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately error."

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, dns

This somewhat related to my last question I asked here. I had tried implementing multi-processing to a script I'm writing to try and make it faster, but after I'd done that it refuses to make any connections. I'm not entirely sure what went wrong, I'm not sure if it's something I've done or if I'm just making too many requests.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akara\PycharmProjects\clientBotTest\venv\lib\site-packages\dns\query.py", line 407, in _udp_recv
    return sock.recvfrom(max_size)
BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

is the full error message I'm getting. This happens whenever I run and Ctrl+C after a few minutes.

This is my full code for the script I'm writing in-case that has anything to do with me getting this error. I'm fairly new to anything like this (I've only done pretty basic Python stuff for a few years).

```
import argparse
import json
from mcstatus import JavaServer

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Minecraft Server Status',
                                 formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--input', type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='UTF-8'), help='Input File')
parser.add_argument('--output', type=argparse.FileType('a', encoding='UTF-8'), help='Output File')
args = parser.parse_args()

with args.input as f:
    ipList = []

    #Formatting Input List
    for line in f:
        ipList.append(line.replace('\n', ''))

    resp = {}

    #Check status of MineCraft Server
    def checkStatus(ip):
        try:
            server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
            status = server.status()
            q = server.query()
            resp['Online'] = True
            resp['address'] = ip
            resp['players_online'] = q.players.names
            resp['players_max'] = q.players.max
            resp['version'] = status.version.name
            resp['plugins'] = q.software.plugins
            with args.output as ofile:
                print(json.dumps(resp), file=ofile)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    for x in ipList:
        checkStatus(x)
```

EDIT: When I print out the error I'm getting it returns:  UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.

Comment: Just use try except and move on? A nonblocking read from a socket will fail if it had nothing to be read at that point

Comment: The problem is that there should be output but there's nothing coming in. I've even made sure to check the list itself.

Comment: 1) CTRL+C is to interrupt the program, so why it is important if you have errors there? 2) The error comes from the dnspython package, which version do you use?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek For the specific input file I'm using to test it, it'd take about an hour to run through the entire thing. I put 5 IPs that I know are active servers at the beginning, so after about a minute the output file should have 5 responses in it. As for dnspython, I'm using 2.2.1 I have also added new info to my post regarding the error I'm getting. Hope it helps.